# Magnetic field in-between two antiparallel wires with the same current

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism

If I have two antiparallel wires with the same current at distance $2a$ apart from each other, how would I go about modeling the magnetic field in between the wires? I know the fields will add but I'm wanting to derive an expression for for the total field at different points in-between the wires.

This isn't a homework problem but the thought of deriving such an expression did come to me from a homework problem where I needed to find the field in the middle of two wires.

Comment: Welcome to Physics Stack Exchange! This is a well presented question, good job! Note that this site supports [mathjax](http://physics.stackexchange.com/help/notation) for mathematical expressions. Also note that homework-like questions should include an explanation of what you have tried and a precise statement of where you are stuck.

Comment: You have answered your own question - you know that you can add the field due to each wire.

Answer (score 1):

Use right hand thumb rule to calculate this. By bio-savart law, we det d**B**  =K*i*(d**l** * **r**)/$r^3$ .
 so in both the cases the cross product gives a downward d**B**. (See the picture)[image]